# Sum distinct rows inner join sqlite android

Tags: android, database, sqlite, sum, android-cursor

My problem :
I have 3 tables, user, debit and user_list. I need in a single query (because I'm using a Cursor on android) and preferably NOT using rawQuery to get the user.name and the sum of all debits linked to that user with status = 1.

For instance:

```
User                      Debit                          User_List

id   |  name              user_id    |   value        user_id    |    status

1    | John               1          | 10.23           1                1
2    | Marie              1          | 22              2                1
                          2          | 2333
```

It should return something like below when the status is equals to 1:

```
name     value

John     32.23
Marie    2333
```

What I have done so far:

```
SELECT (select SUM(debit_value) from debits where debit_status = 0) AS user_balance, user_name AS user_name, status, users.user_id AS user_id, _id FROM users INNER JOIN users_listview ON users.user_id = users_listview.user_id WHERE (status = ?) GROUP BY users._user_id
```

Thanks !

Comment: How about `select name,sum(debit_value) from user,debit group by user.user_id having debit.user_id = user.id;` ?

Comment: @Kedarnath I think your query will fail in `group by` clause

Comment: Sorry guys, I forgot to mention that I had a 3rd table ! But I managed to make it work ! Thank you all for helping me !

Answer (score 0):

use below query

```
select User.name, sum(Value) from User inner join Debit
on User.id=Debit.userid
Group by User.name
```

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
SELECT U.NAME,SUM(COALESCE(D.VALUE,0)) AS TOTAL_VALUE FROM USER U LEFT OUTER JOIN  DEBIT D ON U.ID=D.USER_ID GROUP BY U.NAME
```

Answer (score 0):

My final query:

```
SELECT SUM(debit_value) AS user_balance, user_name AS user_name, status, users.user_id AS user_id, users.user_id AS _id FROM users INNER JOIN users_listview ON users.user_id = users_listview.user_id INNER JOIN debits ON users.user_id = debit_to WHERE (status = ?) GROUP BY debit_to
```

Thank you all !